# Accidentally imported data tables into Master database — Any cleanup needed beyond deleting?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

We accidentally imported some data tables into our Master database with a CREATE TABLE and BULK INSERT script.  It was probably about 20 GB of data before we caught it.

We immediately deleted all of the tables.

What other cleanup or diagnostic tools should we run?  Should we be on the lookout for anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have already deleted the Imported Tables then you are fine. You will not be required to do anything else.

This can happen and to get rid of this Use the Import/Export Wizard or Properly use the databasemame.Schema.Table.

Answer (score 0):

To me, nothing to worry about after you delete all imported tables. But I'd suggest that it may be good for you to check the [master] db's data file and log file size and shrink them if needed to save some space.